# Pandas pivot table, sort values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pivot table in Pandas.

```
df_pivot = df_final.groupby('bm').apply(lambda sub: sub.pivot_table(
    index=['Utm_campaign', 'Time'],
    values=['Cost', 'Install', 'Show', 'Link_cliks', 'Reg', 'Ftd'],
    aggfunc=np.sum,
    margins=True,
    margins_name='Total'
))

# Calculation
df_pivot = df_pivot.assign(Instal_cost = df_pivot.Cost/df_pivot.Install)
df_pivot = df_pivot.assign(Reg_cost = df_pivot.Cost/df_pivot.Reg)
df_pivot = df_pivot.assign(FTD_cost = df_pivot.Cost/df_pivot.Ftd)
df_pivot = df_pivot.assign(CTR = df_pivot.Link_cliks/df_pivot.Show*100)

# Replace Inf
df_pivot.replace([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan], 0, inplace=True)
df_pivot = df_pivot.drop(['Link_cliks', 'Show'], axis=1)

df_pivot = df_pivot.sort_values(by = ["bm", 'Utm_campaign'], axis = 0, ascending=[True, False])
```

I've attached an image from Excel as it is easier to see in tabular format what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Link to image]

I tried using .sort_values() but I couldn't sort '**Cost**'.

Thanks in advance

---

**df_pivot:**

| bm | Utm_campaign | Time | Cost | Ftd | Install | Reg | Instal_cost | Reg_ cost | FTD_cost | CTR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name49438 | Total |  | 2,43 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | OPD_DE_SL_name49438 | 11:00 | 2,43 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| name54908 | Total |  | 8,5 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 4,25 | 8,5 | 0 | 1,02 |
|  | OPD_DE_SL_name54908 | 10:00 | 8,5 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 4,25 | 0 | 0 | 1,02 |
|  |  | 11:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| name56281 | Total |  | 17,76 | 0 | 4 | 3 | 4,44 | 5,92 | 0 | 0,63 |
|  | OPD_DE_name56281 | 11:00 | 17,76 | 0 | 4 | 3 | 4,44 | 5,92 | 0 | 0,63 |
| name57749 | Total |  | 0,01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | OPD_DE_SL_name57749 | 10:00 | 0,01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  |  | 11:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as plain text, we can not copy the contents from image. Please take a look at [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I have edited it for now using https://extracttable.com/ and https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables but please next time add the data as plain text :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_pivot['ucost'] = df_pivot['Cost'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
df_pivot = df_pivot.sort_values(by = ['ucost', "bm", 'Utm_campaign', "Time"], axis = 0, ascending=[False, True, False, True]).drop('ucost', axis=1)
```

---

**res:**

[image]

Comment: Ignore the `index column`. I was trying to create the data frame same as yours. So did `reset_index`. that's why `index column` also got added.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me find the right solution)